# Boost serialization doesn't work with shared_ptr<int>

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

The following piece of code compiles just fine:

```
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>

struct A {
    int i;

    A(): i(0) {}
    A(int i): i(i) {}

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int) {
        ar & i;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>(465);
    std::stringstream stream;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive out{stream};
    out << a;
}
```

Now I would expect that if I replace `A` with `int` then it should also work.

```
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    auto a = std::make_shared<int>(465);
    std::stringstream stream;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive out{stream};
    out << a;
}
```

However, this code doesn't compile, but gives an assertion failure:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:    
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp:277:5: error: static_assert failed "boost::serialization::tracking_level< T >::value != boost::serialization::track_never"
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(
    ^
...
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Boost?

Comment: @Yakk If you save then load a `shared_ptr`, they will point to different places (obviously since you may load from a different program). But if you serialize a `shared_ptr` multiple times to a single archive, then load it, the loaded pointers will point to the same place. It also works with naked pointers and `unique_ptr`s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Boost source code around that assertion:

```
// The most common cause of trapping here would be serializing
// something like shared_ptr<int>.  This occurs because int
// is never tracked by default.  Wrap int in a trackable type
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((tracking_level< T >::value != track_never));
```

Basically, in order to serialize things like `shared_ptr` properly, the pointed-to objects need to be centrally tracked during the serialization process (to identify when multiple pointers point to the same object, so they don't lead to two copies of the object being serialized). Tracking an object is more expensive than not tracking it, though, so primitive types are not tracked (the assumption being that there's gonna be a *lot* of them). Essentially, this makes it impossible to serialize `shared_ptr<primitive_type>` without mucking with the Boost sources. The solution, as the comment says, is to instead serialize some UDT *containing* an int.

Comment: And the canonical source for this is [doc/special.html#objecttracking](http://tinyurl.com/qasswc9) (eg. "_By default, data types designated primitive by Implementation Level class serialization trait are never tracked. If it is desired to track a shared primitive object through a pointer (e.g. a long used as a reference count), It should be wrapped in a class/struct so that it is an identifiable type. The alternative of changing the implementation level of a long would affect all longs serialized in the whole program - probably not what one would intend._")